# getting limited rows at each page when clicking next button

Tags: html, sqlite

This is code from phone gap index HTML page.

```
function querySuccess(tx, results){  
    var len = results.rows.length;  
    var output = ''; 

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    { 
       output = output + '<li id="' + results.rows.item(i).id + '">' + results.rows.item(i).list_action + '</li>';
    } 

    messageElement.html('<p>There are ' + len + ' items in your list:</p>');     
    listElement.html('<ul>' + output + '</ul>');
}
```

After populating this database I need that how to get limited rows at each page, for ex 5 rows after clicking to next button. But the button is not present there. Then how to create it. Also how to pass the current  ID to another HTML page.