# how to display only 4 result in each page using html & sqlite

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

This is me once again as I got some error in previous question in the code. So asking this question once again.

This is code from phonegap app from index html page. I don't know how to get only 4 result from database at each page when a sqlite query processed?

Also I want to add next page button. When clicking on this button next 4 result from database should come. This is code.

```
function querySuccess(tx, results){ 
    var len = results.rows.length; 
    var output = ''; 
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){    
        output = output +       '<li id="' + results.rows.item(i).id + '">' +                results.rows.item(i).list_action + '</li>';
    }

    messageElement.html('<p>There are ' + len +    ' items in your list:</p>'); 
    listElement.html('<ul>' + output + '</ul>');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting limited rows at each page when clicking next button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982771/getting-limited-rows-at-each-page-when-clicking-next-button)

Answer (score 0):

Dividng your solution into 3 phases

**Phase 1**: Using LIMIT Clause you can limit number of rows to be displayed

```
SELECT expressions FROM tables WHERE conditions ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ] LIMIT number_rows OFFSET offset_value;
```

For Example:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, first_name
FROM employees
WHERE favorite_website = 'divyashah.in'
ORDER BY employee_id DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

**Phase 2**:

As the code provided by you is not efficient to explain but still... Now for your Next button

1) Fetch number of rows from your database table (mysql_num_rows).

2) Store that number in a Variable say 'a'.

3) Divide it(a) with 4 and store it in variable 'b'.

4) Use if > if(b!=0) {display next button} else {no need to display}

**Phase 3:**

This will fetch your first four rows i.e. from 0 to 4.

```
<?PHP
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 4")or
die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Now how can you make the next page show the next 4 records?
you simply have to store the value of the starting row in a variable and pass it in the URL as a GET variable. Also have to check if there was a value already passed or not so we can set a default value in case it wasn't (zero to start from first row):

```
<?PHP
//check if the starting row variable was passed in URL or not
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
//otherwise we take the value from the URL
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
?>
```

Now your query should have this new variable ($startrow) in the LIMIT clause

```
<?PHP
//this part goes after the checking of the $_GET var
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $startrow, 4")or
die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Now to see the next 4 records you should have a link which will add 4 to $startrow so you can view the next 4 records

```
<?PHP
//now this is the link..
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+4).'">Next</a>';
?>
```

Comment: How can be this complete example?

Comment: Some efforts are needed from your side too

Comment: I don't get in phase 2 step 3 & 4. Could you explain with example like other example?

Comment: That  your records must be more than four, if not there is no point of showing the Next Button

Comment: So you satisfied with the answer?